# find the closed form of generating function such that $x^1+x^4 + x^9 +x^{16} +x^{25} +...+x^{n^2}+....$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions

I am trying to find the closed form of generating function such that $x^1+x^4 + x^9 +x^{16} +x^{25} + x^{36} +x^{49} +x^{64}+....$

As you realize , their exponentials are the sequence of $1,4,9,16,..., n^2,...$ where $n$ is positive integer. I do not know what i should do , i tried to put some values in $\frac{1}{1-x}$ but it does not satisfy.

NOTE= I am working over generating functions , a solution was suggested but theta function does not satisfy me . I need a closed form like  $\frac{x^3}{1-x^3}$ etc. (It is given randomly ,  $\frac{x^3}{1-x^3}$ does not related to the question )

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Nice problem, actually. I'll be thinking about this ...

Comment: Such a series turns out to involve a family of special functions called [*theta functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function).

Comment: I think it's possible to prove that this will not be a rational function (note that $\frac{x^3}{1-x^3}$ is a rational function i.e. a ratio of polynomials) using some tools involved in identifying such functions. In fact, if the form of this function has been shown to involve a transcendental function, then perhaps such a result can be shown as a proof by contradiction from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is series representation of the famous Jacobi theta function. And in your case this corresponds to the subscript $3$ and hence this sum becomes as follows :
$$\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty x^{k^2}=\frac{1}{2}\left( \vartheta_3 (0,x) -1\right) $$
for $|x|<1$
Note : before actually knowing this much about the function I kind of played with series a lot and was curious to derive ample of identities (approximations actually which I realized afterwards ) similar to this example given :
$$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{e^{k^2}}\approx \frac{\sqrt{\pi } -1}{2}$$
But noticing the first few decimal digits I almost was moved by the fact that this result is correct which isn't after I came to know about this function.

Comment: [OEIS A010052](https://oeis.org/A010052) gives the same generating function.

Comment: @henry Oh yeah it's there. Theta functions are being studied from the beginning however it was first Jacobi and the Ramanujan who nailed the theta functions.;)

Comment: @thomas andrews  It was a typo. I've rectified it. Thank you for notifying.